# displaying total supply of a contract using web3.js and javascript

Tags: web3js, javascript

I wrote a code which can connect to a contract and reads its total supply. here is my code(I removed abi because it was too big and didnt copy it here):

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const rpcURL = "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443"
const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)
const abi = []
const c_address = "0xA964a6dab034A4b5985603f7e86a596c7e0eA96e"
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, c_address)
contract.methods.totalSupply().call((err, result) => { console.log( web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether')) })
```

I watched some tutorials to write this and the last line confuses me. how can I change the last part to make it display the total supply using document.write? I actually need to use this on a html page. can anyone help me? my javascript knowledge is very limited. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can place your javascript logic inside the fat arrow function.

For example:

```js
contract.methods.totalSupply().call((err, result) => {
  if(err){
    console.error('Error: ', err);
    // handle the error here
  }

  let supply = web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether');
  // You can add supply now to whatever part
  // of your page you want it displayed
});
```

If you are using pure html and js then I would suggest using `document.getElementById()` instead of `document.write()` because the latter replaces the entire html page.
Take a look on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808626/how-to-write-inside-a-div-box-with-javascript)
You can also find tutorials on how to write on specific document elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: { document.getElementById( web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether')) } like this? where should I add the id?